# How can I transform non-English text to uppercase in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have the following text:

> żółć gęślą jaźń

If I make it uppercase in Vim (using gUU) under Windows (encoding cp1250) I get:

> żółć GęśLą JAźń

But I should get:

> ŻÓŁĆ GĘŚLĄ JAŹŃ

according to Polish alphabet.

Is there a way to redefine uppercase and lowercase letters in Vim?

Comment: It might be easier to use UTF-8 instead. With this encoding vim uppercases the text correctly for me.

Comment: Yes. For UTF-8 it works correctly. But I need CP1250

Comment: What benefit do you get from using CP1250 instead of UTF-8?

Comment: @romainl - Ability to print it out, for instance. Vim has some utf8 encoding issues.

Answer (score 0):

There's always the brute force method:

```
%s#\%(ż\|ó\|ł\)#\={'ż':'Ż','ó':'Ó','ł':'Ł'}[submatch(0)]#gcI
```

Comment: That example only has 3 letters, but it should only take a few mins to fill in that sub command with all the letters of the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set your locale in Vim properly. Try adding this line to your `vimrc`

```
lang ctype Polish_Poland.1250
```